# Getting arguments from pipe in python program

Tags: python, linux

I need to execute my python program in the following way:
`echo -e arg1|myprogram.py`.

In this way if I try to get the arguemnts passed to my program I get an nothing ( `print(sys.arg)`). How is it possible to get the arguments like that?

Comment: What you're trying to do is to read from stdin, there are plenty of questions about that, now that you know what you're looking for ;-)

Possible duplicate of [Python Read from Stdin with Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182482/python-read-from-stdin-with-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that script

```
import sys

print(sys.argv, sys.stdin.read())
```

And run

> echo "a" | python test.py

```
['test.py'] a
```